# how can i know Geocoder is provided or not android?

Tags: android, gps

In geocoder class document i read below lines

The Geocoder class requires a backend service that is not included in the core android framework. The Geocoder query methods will return an empty list if there no backend service in the platform.

How can I know if my framwork(1.6) providing background service for Geocoder.Currently it gives me null result.

Thanks,
aare.

Comment: It is not the "framework" that provides the backend service for Geocoder - the device implementation does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate the Geocoder class and try a query for which you can be reasonably sure there will be a result.

For example:

```
public boolean isGeocoderImplemented(Context context) {
    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(context);
    List<Address> newyork = coder.getFromLocationName("New York", 10);
    return !newyork.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: Just note - missing network connection will return with false as well.